# What is wrong with this RegEx to match €, $ and £ prices?

Tags: regex

I am pretty new to regex. I am trying to build a regular expression that I can use to find and extract prices from a website that match certain, valid formats.

Let me give you a few examples:

```
€ 14,99    ->  14,99
€14,99     ->  14,99
€1.337,80  ->  1.337,80

£ 4.99     ->  4.99
£4.99      ->  4.99
£4,711.99  ->  4,711.99

$ 8.88         ->  8.88
$14.99         ->  14.99
$4,000,711.99  ->  4,000,711.99
```

I came up with a regex that works pretty well so far:

```
/(((?<=([$£] ?))((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+)|\d+).)|((?<=(€ ?))((\d{1,3}(.\d{3})+)|\d+),))\d{2}(?!\d)/g
```

The first part allows for dollar and pound prices with . as decimal separator and , as thousands separator; the second part does the same for € prices with . and , inverted.

However, this regex finds a few false negatives, e.g.

```
$9,98 -> 9,98
$ 9,98 -> 9,98
£19,98 -> 19,98
```

Those prices should not match the regex; however, they do; and I don't know why :-) There seems to be a problem with the (already condensed) part

```
/(?<=([$£] ?))\d+.\d{2}(?!\d)/g
```

Can anyone who has more experience with RegEx than I have please point me in the right direction and tell what I did wrong, and how I can fix it?

There is a full fiddle with a bunch of examples over here -> https://jsfiddle.net/e0re1Lhc/

Comment: Escape the `.` so that it's `\.`

Comment: What exactly are the matching/non-matching rules here? I'm a little confused.

Comment: FYI: for readability's sake, many regexp languages have modifiers like `/x` which allow you to insert comments and extra whitespace. Unfortunately Javascript does not, although it is possible to use wrappers such as [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re getting false positives (not negatives) because an unescaped `.` matches any character.  To match only a decimal point, escape it with `\.`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comment, the issue you're experiencing is due to `.` being a special character. In regex this matches any character (except `\n` unless otherwise specified - i.e. using the `s`/single-line mode flag in many regex engines).

Also, note that lookbehinds don't work in JavaScript at the moment, although support is nearing! Currently, only Chrome 62+ supports this token. Your best bet is to use capture groups.

I think you're looking for the following regex pattern.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Jk4VF7/2)

```
(?:€ ?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})|[£$] ?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))(?!\d)
```

Similarly, a regex pattern that also allows for numbers without thousands separators, you can use the following

```
(?:€ ?((?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|\d+),\d{2})|[£$] ?((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)\.\d{2}))(?!\d)
```

---

Expand and run the snippet below to see it in use!

```js
(function() {
  console.log("hallo");

  let priceTags = document.querySelectorAll(".p13n-sc-price");

  var re = /(?:€ ?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})|[£$] ?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))(?!\d)/g,
    count = 0;

  priceTags.forEach((e) => {
    let input = e.textContent,
      match;

    while ((match = re.exec(input)) != null) {
      count++;
      console.log(count, "->", match[1] || match[2]);
    }
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Positive Matches</h1>
<ol>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 12,18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 14.18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 12.18</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£12.99</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€4,75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 4,75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€14,75</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$1,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£1,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€1.004,75</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 1,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 1,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 1.004,75</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 1,000,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 1,000,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 1.000.004,75</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 7.99 - $ 12.18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 7.99-£ 12.18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 4,59 - €17,34</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$9.98 - $14.98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£7.99 - £12.18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€4,59 - €17,34</span></li>
</ol>

<h1>Negative Matches</h1>
<ol>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€1,004.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$1.004,75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£1.004,75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€ 4.75</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$9,98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$ 9,98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£19,98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£ 19,98</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$9,98 - $14,98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£7,99 - £12,18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€4.59 - €17.34</span></li>

  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">$9,98 - $14,98</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">£7,99 - £12,18</span></li>
  <li class="listing"><span class="p13n-sc-price">€4.59 - €17.34</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted. If downvoter is still around, would you care to comment why?

Comment: It wasn't me :-) I upvoted, so this is at least back to 0! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!!!